# ng-click and ng-href on the same element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a list that I am populating via ng-repeat of links.

some of these links need to open as links via ui-router, and some need to open as modals via ui-bootstrap.

This is my Html

```
<div class="sub-menu">
  <li ng-repeat="sub in menu track by $index">
    <a ng-controller="ModalController" ng-click="open(sub.click)" ng-href="#/{{sub.link}}">
      <i class="fa {{sub.icon}}"></i> {{sub.name}} </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

and the data looks like this:

```
$scope.menu = [{
    icon: 'fa-plus-square',
    name: 'new',
    click: 'newModal'
}, {
    icon: 'fa-th-list',
    name: 'list',
    link: 'ui_bootstrap.html'
}
```

The problem is, that all links are sent to the ModalController, thus the first link opens a modal, but the second one doesn't reload the page.

I tried adding an if to the ModalController as so:

```
$scope.open = function (link) {
    if (link) {
      var out = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: "views/modals/" + link + ".html",
        controller: "ModalInstanceController",
        resolve: {
          items: function () {
            return $scope.items;
          }
        }
      });
      out.result.then(function (value) {
        $scope.selected = value;
      }, function () {
        $log.info("Modal dismissed at: " + new Date);
      });
    };
  }
```

But that still isn't fixing the problem.

Any solution? or better way to do this?

Comment: Add one flag true/false in your ng-repeat object and use that flag to show modal/href as your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use click only. And in the controller on click, you can check if there is a link then you can use routing else you can open a pop-up.

```
<a ng-controller="ModalController" ng-click="open(sub)">
```

Controller

```
$scope.open = function (sub) {
    if (sub.click) {
      var out = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: "views/modals/" + sub.click + ".html",
        controller: "ModalInstanceController",
        resolve: {
          items: function () {
            return $scope.items;
          }
        }
      });
      out.result.then(function (value) {
        $scope.selected = value;
      }, function () {
        $log.info("Modal dismissed at: " + new Date);
      });
    } else {
      $state.transitionTo(sub.link);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

modify your HTML with this

```
<div class="sub-menu">
  <li ng-repeat="sub in menu track by $index">

  <a ng-controller="ModalController" ng-click="open(sub.click)" ng-if="!(sub.includes('html'))">

   <a ng-controller="ModalController"  ng-href="#/{{sub.link}}" ng-if="sub.includes('html')">
      <i class="fa {{sub.icon}}"></i> {{sub.name}} </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you feel it looks odd try this 
Your Controller function

```
$scope.open = function (sub) {
if(sub.link==""&&sub.click!="")
{
 var out = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: "views/modals/" + sub.click + ".html",
        controller: "ModalInstanceController",
        resolve: {
          items: function () {
            return $scope.items;
          }
        }
      });
      out.result.then(function (value) {
        $scope.selected = value;
      }, function () {
        $log.info("Modal dismissed at: " + new Date);
      });
}
    if(sub.link!=""&&sub.click=="") {
        var landingUrl = "http://" + $window.location.host + "#/"+sub.link;
    $window.location.href = landingUrl;

    }
  }
```

Your HTML as

```
<div class="sub-menu">
  <li ng-repeat="sub in menu track by $index">
    <a ng-controller="ModalController" ng-click="open(sub)" ng-href="#/{{sub.link}}">
      <i class="fa {{sub.icon}}"></i> {{sub.name}} </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

and finally your scope variable as

```
$scope.menu = [{
    icon: 'fa-plus-square',
    name: 'new',
    link: "",
    click: 'newModal'   
}, {
    icon: 'fa-th-list',
    name: 'list',
    link: 'ui_bootstrap.html',
    click: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `ng-href` and ng-click on one element, even if you want to do that.   Then use `$state.go`.
So here

```
$scope.open = function (link) {
  // simply add here $state.go

 $state.go=("write state name", {..add attributes herre if you want to pass})


if (link) {
  var out = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: "views/modals/" + link + ".html",
    controller: "ModalInstanceController",
    resolve: {
      items: function () {
        return $scope.items;
      }
    }
  });
  out.result.then(function (value) {
    $scope.selected = value;
  }, function () {
    $log.info("Modal dismissed at: " + new Date);
  });
};
}
```